# Any idea of compound Poisson processes in betting?

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson

Any suggestions on compound poisson processes in bets of a customer?

Comment: Hi Christopher Cauchi, welcome to Quant.SE! It's not clear to me what you mean here. What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks for your welcome. I have a thesis to work on next year, and I was assigned to do something about Compound Poisson processes about customer betting behaviour in a certain betting company. Any ideas?

Comment: This is still not really clear but I consider customer behaviour as not Quantitative Finance, it could be on stats.stackexchange.com but this question needs editing before I would migrate it.